# Laravel session flash not working in L5.6

Tags: laravel, middleware

If I add the following line:

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```

in my application app/http/kernel.php under the `$middleware` key, it causes an error.

My payment gateway redirection will work perfectly however, the session flash messages are not working...

Also, when I remove the above line, the flash session error stops and the payment gateway response sends me to the homepage. and session also expired.

Comment: Are you placing your routes in web.php? https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.6/routes/web.php

Comment: yes it is. written in web.php only

Comment: How are you flashing the message? I typically go for flashing along with the response. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

Comment: tried flashing with with and session::flash both but not working at all                 $request->session()->flash('error', 'Payment failed!');
        $request->session()->reflash();
        $request->session()->keep(['error', 'success']);                                  return redirect()->back()->with('error','Transaction failed')

Comment: How are you accessing the session data after the redirect `session('error')`? Can you dump your session right after the redirect? `dd(session()->all())` should work